# Bash read a valid phone number

Tags: bash

I am asked to write a script that accepts a 10 digit number i.e. `nnn-nnn-nnnn` The first number cannot start with a `0` and it has to be `10 digits long`. My thought is something like this below.

```
# Create a field separator for each character/number inputed

# if [ value [0] -eq 0 ] ; do (invalid entry)
# if [ value [0] (is a number [1-9]) ] (move on to the next value in array)

# if [ value[1] (is a number [0-9]) (move on to the next value in array)


# all the way through the file....
```

Comment: So did that work when you tried it?

Comment: Use a regular expression

Answer (score 2):

This removes any dashes or spaces, then checks for exactly ten digits.

```
function validphone () {
    case ${1//[ -]/} in
     *[!0-9]* | 0* | ???????????* | \
     ????????? | ???????? | ??????? | ?????? | ????? | ???? | ??? | ?? | ? | '')
        return 1 ;;  # Return failure
     *) return 0 ;;  # Success
    esac
}
```

We check for non-digits, a sequence starting with zero, too long, or (multiple patterns for) too short; otherwise, pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using:

```
read -e -p "Enter phone number: " number
[[ ! $number == 0* && ${#number} == 10 && $number =~ [0-9]+$ ]] &&
echo "Valid" || echo "Not valid"
```

Example with loop:

```
while true; do
read -e -p "Enter phone number: " number
[[ ! $number == 0* && ${#number} == 10 && $number =~ [0-9]+$ ]] && echo "Valid" && break; 
done
```

The while loop will not break if the required conditions aren't met.

**Conditions checked:**

1. doesn't start with 0
2. length is 10
3. all characters are digits between 0 and 9

Comment: This just checks that there is one digit and that the first one is not zero.  You could pass with 1abcdefgh.

Answer (score 0):

The following script reads a number, matches it against a pattern, and reports whether or not the pattern was satisfied.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Phone #: \c"
read pn
valid="valid"
case "$pn" in
[1-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) ;;
*) valid="not valid";;
esac
echo $pn is "$valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a case statement:

```
#!/bin/sh

is_valid_number () {
    case "$1" in
     [1-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
      return 0
      ;;
     *)
      return 1
      ;;
    esac
}

for number in "$@"; do 
    if is_valid_number "$number"; then
        echo "$number is valid"
    else
        echo "$number is not valid"
    fi
done
```